# Rails: Content_For not working with AJAX || "refire" JS files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm loading all my views using ajax. Everything's working great except one thing.. My javascript files aren't being referenced by the view pages being loaded. Here's my coffee-script:

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  user.setupForm()

user =
  setupForm: ->
```

Any way I can "refire" my js files after my ajax has loaded?

---

If any one wants to know how I fixed the 'fire twice' thingy, I just removed the 'ajaxcomplete' part and it works fine

Comment: Why Javascript? Why not just insert my custom part to Coffee directly?

Comment: @BillyChan I'm using a js.erb file with rails

Comment: Got it. If there is no Ruby code you can put it in assets and use foo.js.coffee directly.

Comment: @BillyChan you're right! what was I thinking

Comment: @BillyChan this won't cause my customers to be charged twice on non ajax forms, right?

Comment: I see your points. Yes you only need it on certain page. You can use `javascript_tag` to include it in certain template instead of require it globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done nice job to setup functions, so the effort is minimum. Just call the necessary function again. You can further DRY it if necessary.

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  user.setupForm()

$(document).on('ajaxComplete', ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  user.setupForm()
)

user =
  setupForm: ->
  # .... original codes below
```

Comment: Getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined"

Comment: I'm also loading external javascript, so could that be the reason why?

Comment: @Jon, I have not put your `user` part for simplicity. You still need that of course. :)

Comment: still not working for me. I edited in what I'm using in my question

Comment: @Jon, No, your JS code is wrong. `user` should not be under `$(document).on...`. All these three parts should all be on top level.

Comment: I could kiss you right now!! Thank you. Only problem is this causes it to fire twice but I think I can figure out the rest. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jon, nice you fixed it! `raise CantKissError unless op.gender == 'girl'`